# Can you confirm the positivity of a quantity involving the Stirling numbers of the first kind

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, enumerative-combinatorics, computational-number-theory

Let $s(m,n)$ denote the Stirling numbers of the first kind. For $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, define
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{Q}(m,n)=(-1)^n\sum_{\ell=0}^{2n} \binom{m+\ell-1}{m-1} s(m+2n-1,m+\ell-1)\biggl(\frac{m+2n-2}{2}\biggr)^{\ell}.
\end{equation}
I knew the identities
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{Q}(1,n)&=\biggl[\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^{n}}\biggr]^2,\\
\mathcal{Q}(2,n)&=\biggl[\frac{(2n)!!}{2^{n}}\biggr]^2=(n!)^2,\\
\mathcal{Q}(3,n)&=\biggl[\frac{(2n+1)!!}{2^{n}}\biggr]^2 \sum_{\ell=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(2\ell+1)^2},\\
\mathcal{Q}(4,n)&=\biggl[\frac{(2n+2)!!}{2^{n}}\biggr]^2 \sum_{\ell=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(2\ell+2)^2},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{Q}(5,n)=
\frac{1}{2}\biggl[\frac{(2n+3)!!}{2^{n}}\biggr]^2 \Biggl[\Biggl(\sum_{\ell=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(2\ell+1)^2}\Biggr)^2 -\sum_{\ell=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(2\ell+1)^4}\Biggr]
\end{equation*}
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I guess that

**the quantity $\mathcal{Q}(m,n)$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ is positive.**

Can you confirm the correctness of this guess? Thank you very much.

This problem comes from the main results in the following references.

References

1. B.-N. Guo, D. Lim, and F. Qi, *Maclaurin's series expansions for positive integer powers of inverse (hyperbolic) sine and tangent functions, closed-form formula of specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representation of generalized logsine function*, Appl. Anal. Discrete Math. **16** (2022), no. 2, 427--466; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM210401017G.
2. F. Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstr. Math. **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.

---

**One more problem.**
For given $m\ge1$ and $n\ge0$, is the quantity
$$
\mathfrak{Q}_{m,n}(\ell)=\frac{\mathcal{Q}(m,n+\ell+2)}{\mathcal{Q}(m,n+\ell+1)}\frac{(m+2 n+2 \ell+2)!}{(m+2 n+2 \ell+4)!}(\ell+1) 
$$
an increasing sequence in $\ell\ge0$? Equivalently, is the sequence
$$\tag{OO}
\frac{t(m+2\ell+2n+2,m)}{t(m+2\ell+2n,m)} \frac{(m+2\ell+2n)!}{(m+2\ell+2n+2)!} \ell
$$
decreasing in $\ell\in\mathbb{N}$ for fixed integers $n\ge0$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$? where $t(m,n)$ stands for the first kind of central factorial numbers.

Comment: These are essentially the central factorial numbers $t(n,k)$; see John Riordan, *Combinatorial identities* (1968), 212–217. In particular, your desired result follows from Problem 8 in Chapter 6, which is on page 233.

Comment: @hoboonsuan Can you send me an electronic copy of the book John Riordan, Combinatorial identities (1968)? honest.john.china@gmail.com

Comment: It's on archive.org ([https://archive.org/details/combinatorialide00john](https://archive.org/details/combinatorialide00john)). Requires a free account to access it, and it's a library with restrictions on simultaneous borrowing, but I've used this online copy when chasing references in the past.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I got the book by John Riordan, thank you very much for your information and actions.

Comment: @hoboonsuan
The quantity $\mathcal{Q}(m,n)$ is surely equivalent to the first kind of central factorial numbers $t(j,k)$. I wonder why and how can you see through the relations so quickly and promptly? Is there an explicit or closed-form formula for the first kind of central factorial numbers?

Comment: I’m not sure of the details since I found the connection by computing small values and checking the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/). That said, there are relatively simple relations between $t(n,k)$ and $T(n,k)$, and there are similar-looking expressions for $T$ involving the Stirling numbers (see for example Equation (32) in Chapter 6 of Riordan’s book, on page 216), so that would be where I’d look first to better understand these connections.

Comment: @hoboonsuan 
Till now I haven't proved the positivity of the quantity $\mathcal{Q}(m,n)$ yet. I know it suffices to show the positivity of $(-1)^{j-k}t(2j,2k)$ and $(-1)^{j-k}t(2j-1,2k-1)$, but I haven't find their proof anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

(This is not an answer, it is just too long for a comment. What follows is mostly taken from John Riordan, *Combinatorial Identities* (1968), Chapter 6.)

Let $x^{[n]}=x\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(x+n/2-k)$. The *central factorial number (of the first kind)* is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $x^{[n]}$; that is, $x^{[n]}=\sum_{k=0}^nt(n,k)x^k$. The *central factorial number (of the second kind)* is similarly defined by $x^n=\sum_{k=0}^nT(n,k)x^{[k]}$ (notice the analogy to the Stirling numbers).

To prove your claim, it would suffice to show that
$$\mathcal Q(2m,n)=(-1)^nt(2m+2n,2m),\tag{1}$$
$$\mathcal Q(2m+1,n)=(-1)^nt(2m+2n+1,2m+1),\tag{2}$$ $$\sum_{k=1}^nt(2n,2k)x^{2k-2}=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(x^2-k^2),\tag{3}$$
and
$$\sum_{k=0}^nt(2n+1,2k+1)x^{2k}=4^{-n}\prod_{k=1}^n(4x^2-(2k-1)^2).\tag{4}$$ The identities (3) and (4) follow from the definitions of the central factorial numbers. Perhaps the easiest way to prove (1) and (2) would be to show that they satisfy the definitions directly, or to check that $\mathcal Q$ satisfies the recurrence
$$t(n,k)=t(n-2,k-2)-\frac{1}{4}(n-2)^2t(n-2,k),\tag{5}$$
but I do not have the time to check this right now unfortunately.

---

**Edit (15 October 2023).** We prove that $t(2n,2k)$ has sign $(-1)^{n-k}$. Let us fix some notation first. We write $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$ for the set of the first $n$ positive integers, ${[n]\choose k}=\{S\subset[n]:|S|=k\}$ for the set of all $k$-element subsets of $[n]$, and $[x^k]f(x)$ for the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $f(x)$. The main idea we will use is that $\prod_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)=\sum_{S\subset[n]}\prod_{i\in S}a_i\prod_{i\not\in S}b_i$, as each term in the expansion of this product arises from choosing $a_i$ or $b_i$ in the $i$-th factor; the set $S$ then runs over all possible choices.

Since $\sum_{k=1}^nt(2n,2k)x^{2k-2}=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(x^2-i^2)$, we may compute
\begin{align*}
t(2n,2k)
&=[x^{2k-2}]\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(x^2-i^2)\\
&=[x^{2k-2}]\sum_{S\subset[n-1]}\prod_{i\in S}x^2\prod_{i\in[n-1]\setminus S}(-i^2)\\
&=\sum_{S\in{[n-1]\choose k-1}}\prod_{i\in[n-1]\setminus S}(-i)^2\\
&=(-1)^{n-k}\sum_{S\in{[n-1]\choose k-1}}\prod_{i\in[n-1]\setminus S}i^2.
\end{align*}
The sum in the last term is positive, and so the claim follows.

Comment: I have proved your identities (1) and (2), so it suffices to show $(-1)^{j-k}t(2j,2k)>0$ and $(-1)^{j-k}t(2j+1,2k+1)>0$, but I can't. From your recursive relation (5), I can't see why the positivity $(-1)^{j-k}t(2j,2k)>0$ and $(-1)^{j-k}t(2j+1,2k+1)>0$ are valid.

Comment: Does not the sign of $t(2n,2k)$ follow simply from Vieta theorem a. k. a. expanding the brackets in $\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (x^2-i^2)$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes it does; thanks for pointing it out. I was just writing out the proof of the Vieta theorem specialized to this case in the edit to my post, to make it more self-contained.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Now I see how to prove the positivity $(-1)^{j-k}t(2j,2k)>0$ and $(-1)^{j-k}t(2j-1,2k-1)>0$, which are equivalent to the positivity $\mathcal{Q}(m,n)>0$ in the question. The proof by the Viète theorem at the site https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te_theorem is simpler. Thank you all!